# force local browser cache on php page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, apache

I am using the following code to force a page to "cache".  This seems to work fine in some browsers/devices but not in all.  Is there something I need to add to make sure that the page is cached for the duration specified?  Basically I have a static list of LI elements that total around 500k which is not an issue unless you are on a mobile device.

```
$seconds_to_cache = 3600;
$ts = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + $seconds_to_cache) . " GMT";
header("Expires: $ts");
header("Pragma: cache");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=$seconds_to_cache");
```

Comment: It's a whole section: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html - please suite yourself to the level you need ;) -- also check which additional headers are added by the webserver. The PHP code might not show the whole picture here.

Comment: Mobile devices have specific content cache limits which you may be exceeding. For example - http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/06/28/mobile-browser-cache-limits/

Comment: I think the issue is with mobile browser cache limits  Lloyd's answer should be the accepted solution as it pointed me in the right direciton.